# Gradlew issue with keystore custom path

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have a big issue with gradle when i execute `./gradlew assembleDebug`

This code works :

```
signingConfigs {

    debug {
        def defaultKeystorePath = '/Users/' + System.getenv("USER") + '/.android/debug.keystore'
        storeFile file(defaultKeystorePath)
        storePassword = "android"
        keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword = "android"
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work :

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        def defaultKeystorePath = '/Users/kevinabrioux/.android/debug.keystore'
        storeFile file(defaultKeystorePath)
        storePassword = "android"
        keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
        keyPassword = "android"
    }
```

}

And this is the result of `ls` :

[image]

I don't understand the issue :

> - Where: Build file '/Users/kevinabrioux/Documents/feutre/Feutre/app/build.gradle'
> - What went wrong: Could not compile build file '/Users/kevinabrioux/Documents/feutre/Feutre/app/build.gradle'.
>
>   > startup failed:   General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved it with a simple clean